# Can I override only one method in inheritence?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

My `C++` code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        virtual void f(int i)
        {
            cout << "A's f(int)!" << endl;
        }
        void f(int i, int j)
        {
            cout << "A's f(int, int)!" << endl;
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        virtual void f(int i)
        {
            cout << "B's f(int)!" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.f(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

during compilation I get:

```
g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp 
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:29:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::f(int, int)’
file.cpp:29:9: note: candidate is:
file.cpp:20:16: note: virtual void B::f(int)
file.cpp:20:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

When I tried to use override after B's f(int), I got the same error.

Is it possible in C++ to override only 1 method? I've been searching for a code example using `override` that will compile on my machine and haven't found one yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual method causes compilation error in Derived class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274723/virtual-method-causes-compilation-error-in-derived-class)

Comment: No, sorry, that was another problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: rationale behind hiding rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837399/c-rationale-behind-hiding-rule)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overriding the name "f" as a method name. So any overload will be overridden as well.

You could use the `using` key word, just to tell the compiler to look at the base class as well:

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
        using A::f;
        virtual void f(int i)
        {
            cout << "B's f(int)!" << endl;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that your virtual function `f()` in class `B` **hides** `A`'s  non-virtual overload with an identical name. You can use a `using` declaration to bring it into scope:

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
        using A::f;
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^

        virtual void f(int i)
        {
            cout << "B's f(int)!" << endl;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You're being bitten by how name lookup works in C++. The compiler searches through successive scopes until it finds a scope with at least one item with a matching name.

Assuming that item is a function, it then does overload resolution among the functions with that name that it found at that scope. If none of those works, it does *not* keep searching more scopes to find a better fit.

You can, however, get it to search the parent's class in this case:

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
        using A::f;
        virtual void f(int i)
        {
            cout << "B's f(int)!" << endl;
        }
};
```

At first glance, it might appear that the `using` statement could produce ambiguity. For example, with the `using A::f;` there are now *two* `f(int)` functions visible in `B`'s scope (`A::f(int)` and `B::f(int)`). C++ has some rules to cover this as well, so if you add (for example) `b.f(3);` in `main` (with the `using A::f;` in place) you still won't get ambiguity -- it'll call `b::f(int)` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

The function `f` defined in derived class hides the base class functions by the name `f`.
To bring the hidden function in scope of derived class you need to add:

```
using A::f;
```

to your base class definition.

**Good Read:**

**[What's the meaning of, Warning: Derived::f(char) hides Base::f(double)?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to override just one method of a class, make it virtual. Non virtual will be shadowed when declared in a inherited class.